# JavaScript Function to change HTML not working

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I have an assignment to do the following: Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" to the alt text of the preview image.

I have tried this:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=element.alt;
}
```

This is my HTML code for the div:

```
<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "img.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)">
```

It is not working for me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `element` to be in that function?

Comment: you tag `img` doesn't have an id 'image'

Comment: Sorry, the div that I want to change is: <div id = "image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
 </div>

Comment: When i hover over the image, i want the writing in the div to change to the alt text of the image. And i am not succeeding!

Answer (score 0):

this should work, you have to get the attribute value first in order to set it

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    var x = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute('alt')
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML= x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "img.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this);">
<div id="image">

</div><!--  -->

<script>
function upDate(previewPic){
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=previewPic.alt;
}</script>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! can you explain why so i know for next time?

Comment: here your using element.alt instead of previewPic.alt please check the function passed parameter and used parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
  function upDate(previewPic){
   var image = document.getElementById("YourimgId");
   document.getElementById("image").innerHTML= image.getAttribute("alt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not define the id of the Image tag
Ref:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml
Also, an alter message has another div tag. That is better for the clear output